How to return Observable<T> from Promise?
I am trying to return an  authResult from the following method but it looks like all execution paths do not return a value.
Here's my method:
 public loginWithFacebook():  Observable<AuthResult> {
        this.fbService.login().then((authResponse: any) => {
            const accessToken = authResponse.accessToken;    
            return   this.model.loginWithFacebook(accessToken).pipe(tap(res => this.setSession(res)), shareReplay());         
          
          });         
      } 

here's the error message:
A function whose declared type is neither 'undefined', 'void', nor 'any' must return a value.
How can I rewrite this to return Observable?
Thanks for any attention.

you can convert the promise to an observable using  rsjx from
import { from, Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { switchMap, tap, shareReplay } from 'rxjs/operators';

public loginWithFacebook(): Observable<AuthResult> {
    return from(this.fbService.login()).pipe(
        switchMap((authResponse: any) => {
            const accessToken = authResponse.accessToken;
            return this.model.loginWithFacebook(accessToken);
        }),
        tap(res => this.setSession(res)),
        shareReplay()
    );
}


Thanks for the answer @hezy
